# AWS Glue API not recognizing partitions with hyphen

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-glue

I have data in S3 that is partitioned by category and date as follows:

```
s3://mybucket/category=1/date=2018-08-30/data1.json
s3://mybucket/category=1/date=2018-08-31/data2.json
s3://mybucket/category=2/date=2018-08-30/data3.json
s3://mybucket/category=2/date=2018-08-31/data4.json
```

After running the crawler, I have two partition keys in my metadata table: one for `category`, the other for `date`. I want to retrieve partitions that match certain keys using the [GetPartitions API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_GetPartitions.html) so I began experimenting with the AWS CLI. If I run this command:

`aws glue get-partitions --database-name mydb --table-name mytable --expression "category=1" --region us-west-2`

I successfully retrieve the partition as expected. However, I tried the following command:

`aws glue get-partitions --database-name mydb --table-name mytable --expression "category=1 AND date=2018-08-30" --region us-west-2`

and the response was

> An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the
>   GetPartitions operation: Unsupported expression '2018 - 08 - 30'

Another command that produced this error was

`aws glue get-partitions --database-name mydb --table-name mytable --expression category=1\ AND\ date=2018-08-30 --region us-west-2`

I also tried modifying the call by using the following command:

`aws glue get-partitions --database-name mydb --table-name mytable --expression "category=1 AND date=2018\-08\-30" --region us-west-2`

which gave me the error

> An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the GetPartitions operation: Lexical error at line 1, column 35.  Encountered: "\" (92), after : ""

Is the GetPartitions API able to handle expressions for partitions that contain hyphens? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 5):

Partitions that are initially generated by a crawler in AWS Glue will have type `String` in the metadata catalog. While some of my categories contained hyphens, they were in uuids (i.e. `category=so36-fkw1-...`) so they were not interpreted as expressions. On the other hand, the dates contain only numeric characters and `-` which was the root of the problem. I was able to fix it by enclosing the dates in singular quotes as follows:

`aws glue get-partitions --database-name mydb --table-name mytable --expression category=1\ AND\ date=\'2018-08-30\' --region us-west-2`